# How to show different values in a text box based on an IF statement Access 2010

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I am totally new to VBA.
I am trying to get a text box in a form to show a different value based on a selection of a dropdown menu.
e.g 
The dropdown has 4 values : A, B, C, D (gets them from a table)
For each of the values there is an estFees field(i.e A estFees, B estFees, etc)

I created a textBox in a form and I would like: 
When A is selected in the drop down => the text in the textBox to show A estFees etc

This is what i tried so far:
In the After Update event of the textBox I wrote this statement:

```
if me.cboJob.value = "A" then me.textBox.text = Tables![tableA]![estFees]
```

Cant get it to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reckon you either need to base your combo on a query or to use DLookup, I recommend the first possibility, eg

```
 SELECT t1.OptionValue, t2.estFees
 FROM Table1 t1
 INNER JOIN  TableA t2
 ON t1.Optionvalue = t2.OptionValue
```

You can then set the textbox to:

```
 Me.MyCombo.Column(1)
```

Note that the count starts from zero.

DLookUp would suggest

```
=DLookup("estFees","TableA", "OptionValue='" & MyCombo & "'")
```

There are a number of variables, the above s a sketch.